# Time Selector should not let me select time more than now

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datetimepicker

I have 2 textboxes. One for Date and one for time.
[image].
I can set maxDate: `new Date` but that will ake it for every date I pick up from the calendar.
I also tried

```
$('#datetimepickerExample').datetimepicker({
                format: 'LT', stepping: 1, autoclose: true,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Date_Txt").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
```

where "ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Date_Txt" is the Date Textbox but it doesn't work. So when I pick an earlier date I can select all the 24 hours but when I select today it should limit me to the current time.

Comment: can u plz post ur code as a working snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying the method I've written below, I encourage you to read the plugin documentation [here](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). I did not read whole documentation but I wanted to point out at least a direction for you.

1 - You should get current system date and time.

You can achieve that with [JavaScript GetDate() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp)

```
function getNow() { 
    var e = new Date, 
    month = e.getMonth() + 1, 
    date = e.getDate(), 
    year = e.getFullYear(); 
    month < 10 && (month = "0" + month.toString()), date < 10 && (date = "0" + date.toString()); 
    var currentTime = e.getHours() + ":" + e.getMinutes();
    var currentDate = month + "/" +  date + "/" + year; 

    //currentDate
    //03/27/2021   

    //currentTime
    //11:20
}
```

2 - If current date equals to the date you've picked you should limit the max time input to the current time. I believe you can achieve that with the code below. As I've said I did not read the documentation for the plugin you are using.

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Event_Date_Txt").datepicker({
    onSelectDate:function(currentTime){
      $('#datetimepickerExample').datetimepicker("option", "maxTime", currentTime);
    }
});
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple function that solves this:

```
const isInThePast = date => {
    const now = new Date()
    if (typeof date !== typeof now) return "Invalid Date"
    else return date < now ? true : false
}
```

You can call this function on every date change event and if it returns `true`, set the value, if it returns `false` give the user some sort of warning and keep the previous value.